# Proof whether or not it is Hausdorff (T_2) space $X = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\alpha\} $ with $\alpha \notin \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\alpha\} $ with $\alpha \notin \mathbb{R}$. In $X$ we have the topology $\tau$ with the basis $$B = \{(a,b): a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b\}\cup \{(−\epsilon, 0) \cup \{\alpha\}\cup(0, \epsilon) : \epsilon > 0 \}$$

I want to show if $(X, \tau)$ is Hausdorff ($T_2$) or not, I tried to show that the open sets do not collide but I am confused with the $\alpha$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Can you separate $\alpha$ from $0$?

Comment: Can you separate $0$ and $\alpha$ by open neighborhoods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space will be Hausdorff if for all $x,y\in X$ with $x \ne y$ there are $U, V \in \tau$ with $x \in U, y \in V$ with empty intersection, $U \cap V = \emptyset$, but we can see that $x= 0, y = \alpha$ can't be separated with open disjoint sets.

$U, V\in \tau$, such that $0 \in U, \alpha \in V$, for the definition of $B$, $0 \in B_1 = (a,b)$, $\alpha \in B_2 = (-\epsilon,0) \cup \{\alpha\} \cup (0,\epsilon)$ with $a<0<b$ and $\epsilon > 0$, because $((a,b) \cap (-\epsilon,0)) \ne \emptyset$, then $ \emptyset \ne B_1 \cap B_2 \subset U \cap V$ and the space is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

This space is sometimes referred to as [the line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins). $0$ and $\alpha$ cannot be separated by open neighborhoods.